# Mainframe - ¿Mostrar en un solo spool los Display del programa principal y del llamado?

Tags: cobol

Cobol II
Tengo una rutina que manda a llamar a otra, pero requiero ver los display que puse en ambos programas en el mismo spool, ya que los display que se reflejan en la ejecución solo son los de la rutina principal y no la de la rutina llamada

Alguien tiene noción sobre esto?

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.